# Trying to read file but not finding the path?

Tags: grails, file-io, groovy

Question/Answer [Read a file in groovy into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729302/how-to-read-a-file-in-groovy-into-a-string) is simple, except I get a FileNotFound exception no matter where I move the file, e.g. even to the root directory on a linux box.

If I do:

```
  String cpni = new File('/cpni_p').text
```

and the file cpni_p resides right in the root directory of the system (i.e. make it as simple as possible), I get a

```
 FileNotFoundException: \cpni_p (the system cannot find the file specified)
```

How do I fix this?   I'm open to direct Java too -- just want to get it to work.

Comment: Do you have read permission for the file?

Comment: Yes, -rw-r--r-- are the permissions, for owner, group, world.   I can get it to work on DOS fine with no errors -- just one line -- but doesn't work on Linux for ? reason.

Comment: my guess is, that you are leaving something out here. the error shows `\...` - i doubt any unix would change to a backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a directory level privilege problem.