# How to read a file in Groovy into a string, without knowing the path to the file?

Tags: string, file, groovy, io

In extension to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729302/how-to-read-a-file-in-groovy-into-a-string).

Is it possible to read a file into a string without knowing the path to the file? - I only have the file as a 'def'/type-less parameter, which is why I can't just do a .getAbsolutePath()

To elaborate on this, this is how I import the file (which is from a temporary .jar file)

```
def getExportInfo(path) {
  def zipFile = new java.util.zip.ZipFile(new File(path))

  zipFile.entries().each { entry ->
    def name = entry.name
    if (!entry.directory && name == "ExportInfo") {
      return entry
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the file"? Is it a `File` object that you have in that type-less parameter, then it is the same. Groovy is duck-typing, so if it is `File` object, you can use it as a `File` object, even if the variable type is undefined. What exactly do you have?

Comment: @Vampire No it is not a file object, edited to explain

Comment: @JonasPraem,  what is a `type-less parameter` ? and why did you put in your question zip file reding? can you explain what do you need?

Comment: So you want to read the contents of `entry` or what?

Comment: @Vampire yes, I read the content of entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ZipEntry` is not a file, but a `ZipEntry`.

Those have almost nothing in common.

With `def is = zipFile.getInputStream(entry)` you get the input stream to the zip entry contents.

Then you can use `is.text` to get the contents as `String` in the default platform encoding or `is.getText('<theFilesEncoding>')` to get the contents as `String` in the specified encoding, exactly the same as you can do on a `File` object.