# how to read content of a xqy file in gradle and pass it to a gradle task as a string value?

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

I have a xqy file with path a/b/sample.xqy in ml-gradle project which is inserting a custom dictionary in to the DB.

I want to run that xquery file as part of a gradle task. I am able to run the code by providing the code in string format but wanted to run through a file.

Please help:

Gradle task:

```
task Task1(type: com.marklogic.gradle.task.ServerEvalTask) {
    
    xquery = <how to run the sample.xqy here>
}
```

Comment: `file('sample.xqy').text`?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by tim_yates, and also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7729354/918496), you can use something like this:

```
task Task1(type: com.marklogic.gradle.task.ServerEvalTask) {
    String fileContents = new File('oneplusone.xqy').getText('UTF-8')
    xquery = fileContents
}
```

Any output is printed to console:

```
> Task :Task1
Task ':Task1' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
2
Releasing connection
```

HTH!